# MySQL get list of start time and end time conflict

Tags: mysql

Need help for MySQL query for retrieving record of class schedule that is conflict in the given time.

Ex.

```
SchedID StartTime EndTime
1       09:00:00  13:00:00
2       08:30:00  10:00:00
3       11:00:00  15:00:00
4       07:30:00  08:30:00
5       11:30:00  13:00:00
```

I would like to retrieve the list that is conflict in this given time
Start Time = 09:00:00
End Time = 11:00:00

The record will yield following result:

```
SchedID StartTime EndTime
1       09:00:00  13:00:00
2       08:30:00  10:00:00
3       11:00:00  15:00:00
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: That's solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found my answer here [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Heres my query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE (start_time < givenEndTime) 
AND (end_time > givenStartTime);
```

This works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.schedid, a.starttime, a.endtime
FROM
    tbl_name a, tbl_name b 
WHERE ((b.starttime > a.starttime AND b.starttime < a.endtime) 
    OR (b.endtime > a.starttime AND b.endtime < a.endtime))
ORDER BY schedid
```